# how to bind whole datatable data to RichTextBox

Tags: c#

I want to bind complete `DataTable` data to `RichTextBox`, but i am getting only one cell by using this code below. How can i get the first row data to `RichTextBox`?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"data source=CENSYS01\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=myTest; Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from student", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
richTextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "Sno" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to bind a db to richtextbox, i would suggest you rather use a gridview. Its much more flexible and has a nice way of showing off the data.

Check this page, has good stuff about how to use gridviews

http://www.ezineasp.net/category/ASP-Net-C-Sharp-GridView-Control.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of these options:

- Change your query to bring all the columns concatenated in one, then
  bind this  column to the richtextbox.
- Concat the values in a new datatable column (this link may help you - [How to add New Column with Value to the Existing DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426828/how-to-add-new-column-with-value-to-the-existing-datatable))