# Call session in crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

I call this static web method in jquery and I populate the table with the help of jquery
Data is successfully display in table . In web form page there is one drop-down and two date-picker (from date & to date) according to selection of these values data is display in table now I want to create crystal report when I click on export button then table data ,drop down value & date-picker value will be display in report

I store dt in session and call that want to call in crystal report and I add crystalreportviewer in crystal report

I have web static webmethod i.e

```
[WebMethod]
public static string search_data(DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate, string region)
{
        try
        {
            string result = "";
            Ts1 td = new T1();
            DateTime frDate = new DateTime(fromdate.Year, fromdate.Month, fromdate.Day, 0, 0, 0);
            DateTime to_Date = new DateTime(todate.Year, todate.Month, todate.Day, 23, 59, 59);
            List<griddataresult_Result> dq = td.griddataresult(frDate, to_Date, region).ToList();

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("OwnerName", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("RegNo", typeof(string));
                foreach (var c in dq)
                {

                    dt.Rows.Add(c.ID, c.OwnerName, c.RegNo);
                } 

             DataTable dtt= (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["datagrid"];               
                result = DataSetToJSON(dt);              
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
 }
```

**UPDATE**

now i add this in webform

```
private void BindReport(ReportDocument crystalReport, DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate, string region)
    {


        TrackDataEntities1 t = new TrackDataEntities1();
        crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("data.rpt"));
        List<griddataresult_Result> dsc = t.griddataresult(fromdate, todate, region).ToList();
        crystalReport.SetDataSource(dsc);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
    }
    protected void Report_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataTable dt = Session["datagrid"] as DataTable;
        ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
        //crystalReport.SetParameterValue("@fromdate", fromdate.Value);
        //crystalReport.SetParameterValue("@todate", todate.Value);
        //crystalReport.SetParameterValue("@region", regiondrop.SelectedValue);
        BindReport(crystalReport,Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate.Value), Convert.ToDateTime(todate.Value), regiondrop.SelectedValue);

    }
```

when i click on search then table data is display and then i when i click on report button table is disappear and blank report is display

Comment: First Create crystal report and then create the ReportDocument Object , load your crstalreport by giving the path where you had added your crystal report and pass the parameter like objreport.SetParameterValue("@frmdate",frmdate); and then bind the crstalreportviewer.ReportSource=objreport;crstalreportviewer.Databind();

Comment: check update please @ManishGoswami

Comment: check update @ManishGoswami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add following code inside your ButtonClick Event

```
 protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     { 
    dynamic rpt = new ReportDocument();
    ApplyCRLogin(rpt);
    DataSet dtu = new DataSet();
        // Your Stored Procedure Here 
       // Bind dtu to the ObjReport
       rpt .Database.Tables["Command"].SetDataSource(dtu.Tables[0]);
     // Here Command is name which you can see inside Field Explorer in Crystal Report Design Mode 
       // Then Pass your SP parametrs 
        rpt.SetParameterValue("@dtFromDate", txtFromDate.Text);
        rpt.SetParameterValue("@dtToDate", txtToDate.Text);

        //After this Export your Crstal Report  to  PDF
      ExportToPDF(rpt);
     }

     public void ApplyCRLogin(CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument oRpt)
            {
                CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Database oCRDb = oRpt.Database;
                CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables oCRTables = oCRDb.Tables;
                CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo oCRTableLogonInfo;
                CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo oCRConnectionInfo = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo();
                oCRConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "DatabaseName";
                oCRConnectionInfo.ServerName = "DBSRV_NAME";
                oCRConnectionInfo.UserID = "UserID";
                oCRConnectionInfo.Password = "Password";
                foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table oCRTable in oCRTables)
                {
                    oCRTableLogonInfo = oCRTable.LogOnInfo;
                    oCRTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = oCRConnectionInfo;
                    oCRTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(oCRTableLogonInfo);
                }
            }
```

[How to Export Crystal Report to PDF](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-Crystal-Report-on-Button-Click-to-Word-Excel-PDF-and-CSV-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: but i fromdate in datetime format.. i mean datetime picker

Comment: No issue with that, kindly pass datetime datattype to the frmdate and @todate in SP / or keep as it is varchar

Comment: why you create ApplyCRLogin ? i use linq and database name user id etc are already configure in web.congif

Comment: Does your crystal report asking you for parameter, if not then remove the SetParameter part assign setdatasource(dsc);

Comment: i just want to display dropdown and datepicker value in report

Comment: Add your dropdown value and Date  value to the datatable , and then  just drag and drop it on crystal report

Comment: [Check Here to Add new Column with value  to Exisiting Datable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426828/how-to-add-new-column-with-value-to-the-existing-datatable)

Comment: check my update question i post image.. in this there is table data and dropdodwn and date values now i want to display this data in report